# How do I update Moltin to v2 using IOS, Xcode, and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, api, sdk, moltin

I have been trying to create a shopping app for the past few weeks and have gotten everything to work while using Moltin except showing what is in my Cart in my tableview. I want to try to update my Moltin to version 2 in order to use the new apis to get the cart to work.

Does anyone know how to check which version you are currently using of the software as well as how to update it?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the pod file with new one and install again.